# POST values to third party payment site from my php without using header redirect

Tags: php, session, post, redirect, paypal

I have the following php code

```
<?php

    $token_cipherText=$_POST['tokenex_cipherText'];
    $token=generateToken($tokenex_cipherText);  
    $merchantid="example";
    $Password="example1";
    $remoteIP='11.22.95.5';
    $customerReferenceNo = $_POST['customerReferenceNo'];
    $amount=$_POST['amount'];
    $currencyCode='356';

    $expiryMonth=$_POST['expiry_month'];
    $expiryYear=$_POST['expiry_year'];
    $securityCode=$_POST['cvv'];
    $cardHolderName=$_POST['name_on_card'];
    $cardType=$_POST['selectedRadioValue'];


       if($cardType=='radio1')
    {
        $cardType='CC';
    }
    if($cardType=='radio2')
    {
        $cardType='DB';
    }   


    $cardProvider=$_POST['ccType'];
    if($cardProvider=='visa_electron')
    {
        $cardProvider='visa';
    }
    if($cardProvider=='mastercard')
    {
        $cardProvider='mc';
    }
    if($cardProvider=='maestro')
    {
        $cardProvider='maest';
    }
    if($cardProvider=='sbi_maestro')
    {
        $cardProvider='sbime';
    }
    $cardProvider=strtoupper($cardProvider);

    $name=$cardHolderName;
    $mobileNo=$_POST['mobileNo'];
    $Email=$_POST['email'];
    $merchant_id=$_POST['merchant_id'];

    $sql=mysql_query("select * from card_token where token='$token'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($numrows==0)
    {
        $sql=mysql_query("insert into card_token value('','$token','$merchant_id',now())");
    }

    $sql=mysql_query("update payment_tools_transactions set token_id='$token', cardHolderName='$cardHolderName', cust_Email='$Email', mobileNo='$mobileNo', trans_type='$cardType', cardProvider='$cardProvider', trans_amount='$amount' where trans_refNo='$customerReferenceNo'");

    $checksum = $merchantid."|".$_POST['amount']."|".$customerReferenceNo;  
    $checksum = hash('sha256', $checksum);  
    $data='tokenNo='.$token.'&securityCode='.$securityCode.'&cardExpiryMonth='.$expiryMonth.'&cardExpiryYear='.$expiryYear.'&cardHolderName='.$cardHolderName.'&transactionAmount='.$amount.'&paymentMode='.$cardType.'&currencyCode='.$currencyCode.'&customerReferenceNo='.$customerReferenceNo.'&cardProvider='.$cardProvider.'&name='.$name.'&mobileNo='.$mobileNo.'&email='.$Email.'&password='.$Password.'&amount='.$_POST['amount'].'&remoteIP='.$remoteIP.'&checkSum='.$checksum;

    $encryption_key = "CE5D964";
    $desEncryptedData = encryptText_3des($data, $encryption_key);
    $desEncryptedData = urlencode($desEncryptedData); 

    $url='https://payment.paykml.com/PGCCDCToken/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId='.$merchantid.'&data='.$desEncryptedData;    //URL for CC authentication   
    header("location:$url");
```

An html form posts some values into this php and the above code is executed and using the header `header("location:$url");` these parameters are redirected to `$url='https://payment.paykml.com/PGCCDCToken/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId='.$merchantid.'&data='.$desEncryptedData;`

But the problem im facing is,the redirect url is exposed like `https://payment.paykml.com/PGCCDCToken/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId=example&data=**********`

SESSION CANNOT BE USED SINCE IAM REDIRECTING TO A THIRD PARTY PAYMENT PROCESSING SITE.I dont know if I could hide the parameters by using sessions.

My question is is there any alternate way of posting data which is equivalent to http header redirect? so that the data is not sent through the url?

I could succeed this by using curl

```
//Copy paste all the code till here...
    $encryption_key = "CE5D964";
    $desEncryptedData = encryptText_3des($data, $encryption_key);
    $desEncryptedData = urlencode($desEncryptedData); 


    $url='https://payment.paykml.com/PGCCDCToken/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId='.$merchantid.'&data='.$desEncryptedData; 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $auth = curl_exec($curl);
    if($auth)
    { 
    header("Location:success.php"); //Redirect to a success page after payment.
    exit;
    }
```

Thanks to @Shankar damodar and @Basid saeed for helping me to solve this

Comment: Do they support web services? If yes, you can simply use a cURL function to POST data.

Comment: They havnt mentioned that.Im trying to check if curl is working

Comment: No harm in trying. @Shankar Damodaran's code will most definitely work.

Comment: Check the answer by shankar below.I tried that code for curl but the php is not loading.instead of givin the url completely,will curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [**`cURL`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do the process.

```
//Copy paste all the code till here...
    $encryption_key = "CE5D964";
    $desEncryptedData = encryptText_3des($data, $encryption_key);
    $desEncryptedData = urlencode($desEncryptedData); 


    $url='https://payment.paykml.com/PGCCDCToken/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId='.$merchantid.'&data='.$desEncryptedData; 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $auth = curl_exec($curl);
    if($auth)
    { 
    header("Location:success.php"); //Redirect to a success page after payment.
    exit;
    }
```

Comment: Shankar,i have user cURL as you suggested.I used the code above.After posting,my php is not loading.That is after I fill the form,click submit,it went to mysite.com/process.php and the process.php is not loading.

Comment: No the php stops loading.See usually it worked like,after sending the datats to the url,the thrid party site redirect me to a reponse url from their end,so "succes.php" kind of thing does not exist.hey instead of using     $url='https://payment.paykml.com/PGCCDCToken/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId='.$merchantid.'&data='.$desEncryptedData;  will postfield works?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending it via POST using cURL. I believe the following code will work.

```
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);
$encryption_key = "CE5D964";
$desEncryptedData = encryptText_3des($data, $encryption_key);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
$fields = array(
    'merchantId' => urlencode($merchantId),
    'data' => urlencode($desEncryptedData)
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.Anyway Its working with curl :)..Thank you so much for the help